# REPL with features of modern shell

Tags: shell, scripting

I am creating a script (in Lisp, though this can apply to any language with a REPL) which users interface with using the language's REPL. But this does not include even basic interactive features like remembering history. I am wondering if it is possible to tell a terminal emulator to interpret commands using an arbitrary language, instead of the built-in language.

Thanks!

Comment: The "built-in language" *is* an arbitrary language. *Pick that first.* "sh", "powershell", your-choice-language? If you're writing your own REPL you may be interested in the various [readline libraries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline); but note this is not (normally) a product of the terminal nor does it make the shell somehow understand your languages/environment.

Comment: But the point is that there are features of the terminal (such as hitting the up arrow in order to go to the previously entered command) which have nothing to do with the language that is being entered. If I run 'sbcl' I can interpret lisp code but now with the features of the shell I'm using.

EDIT: OK, it looks like if I can combine Readline with Lisp I can get what I want. If it works, I'll come back and say something.

Comment: A readline-style REPL (of which there are many) is actually generally extremely weak compared to what a good editor with SLIME/SWANK-style interaction with the interpreter you're working with will provide. If you're looking for something readline-style, I'd argue that you're setting your sights far too low. (Think interactive debugging, inline documentation lookup, syntax-aware indentation and formatting, syntax highlighting, etc... all with the normal immediate evaluation behavior of a REPL at hand).

Comment: ...consider the Emacs Live intro at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-jSePveaIPA for an idea of what to look for re: minimum acceptable featureset.

Answer (score 1):

OK, follwoing the advice of user2864740, I looked at GNU Readline, which is the library the provides much of the functionality that I'm looking for. I'm going to switch to Guile Scheme instead of Common Lisp since Guile supports Readline out of the box. However, it looks like it can work in Common Lisp as well: http://www.cliki.net/sb-readline

Answer (score 1):

Yet another approach might be to start the editor emacs, run

```
M-x shell
```

and in this shell run your Lisp REPL. You get a lot of feature for free, like command history.